# Why does appending at 3 lines back cause it to crash?

Tags: javascript, html

So. This is the starting code for a javascript parser that I'm working on. What's wrong is this: It crashes any time that let is in there. So if I try to type, it just freezes the page so I have to reload. The effect only takes place after I start to type, since it's an `onchange` event. Can someone helps me? All helps are appreciated!

```js
document.write('not working');
let jsAreas = document.getElementsByClassName('jsArea')
document.write('Not working')
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
let commenter = document.getElementById('commenter')
for(let i = 0; i < jsAreas.length; i++){
    
    let jsArea = jsAreas[i]
    jsArea.addEventListener('keyup', e =>  {
        commenter.textContent = ''
        let varRegex = /let/g
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName('b');
        
        while(b.length) {
            var parent = b[ 0 ].parentNode;
            while( b[ 0 ].firstChild ) {
                parent.insertBefore(  b[ 0 ].firstChild, b[ 0 ] );
            }
             parent.removeChild( b[ 0 ] );
        }
        while(varRegex.test(jsArea.innerHTML)){
            commenter.textContent += varRegex.lastIndex
            jsArea.innerHTML = jsArea.innerHTML.splice(varRegex.lastIndex - 3, 0, '<b>')
            jsArea.innerHTML = jsArea.innerHTML.splice(varRegex.lastIndex + 3, 0, '</b>')
        }
        commenter.textContent += `Comment: This is the found: ${jsArea.innerHTML.match(varRegex)}. This is the other thing: ${jsArea.innerHTML}. The last index is: ${varRegex.lastIndex} `
    })
}
```

```html
<!-- This is a static file -->
<!-- served from your routes in server.js -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Glitch!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A cool thing made with Glitch">
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/edit/favicon-app.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's client-side javascript file -->
    <script src="/client.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jsArea" contenteditable="true">let=</div>
    <p id='commenter'>
      Comments:
    </p>
    <footer>
      Made with <a href="https://glitch.com">Glitch</a>!
    </footer>

    <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
    <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rare-leek.glitch.me/client.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `while` loops?

Comment: It doesn't return any errors. When I do -2 or - 1, it's fine. But - 3 is the bad thing

Comment: what you have is an infinite loop - debug, debug, debug

Comment: Infinite loop how?

Comment: I suspect one of those `while` loops is creating an infinite loop. You need to debug using `console.log` or something like that to find one which line exactly caused the problem.

Comment: Ohhhh. When I edit innerHTML, it restarts the while loop. So I changed it to textcontent that I was lopping through. Thanks